# How to solve the polynomial equation $\sum_{i=1}^{i=m} \frac{l_i}{l_i - x} = n$?

Tags: polynomials, algorithms

Let m and n be strictly positive integers, and a set of m real positive numbers $$l_{i, i \in \{ 1, m \}}.$$
I want to solve numerically: $$\sum_{i=1}^{i=m} \frac{l_i}{l_i - x} = n$$
finding the m solutions x to this equation.
I look for an effective algorithm to do it for values of m like 50, 100, 1000, or more.

Any idea?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Given

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{i=m} \frac{\ell_i}{\ell_i-x} = n.
$$

Due to the symmetry we consider $\ell_i$ to be ordered, such that $\ell_i < \ell_{i+1}$.
Let us write

$$
f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{i=m} \frac{\ell_i}{\ell_i-x}.
$$

---

We see that

$$
f'(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{i=m} \frac{\ell_i}{(\ell_i-x)^2},
$$

whence $f'(x)>0$.
We also note that

$$
f(\ell_k - \epsilon) < 0,
$$

and

$$
f(\ell_k + \epsilon) > 0,
$$

So there is always a solution for

$$
\ell_i < x < \ell_{i+1}.
$$

---

As

$$
f(x) < 0\ \textrm{for}\ x > \ell_m,
$$

we find the last solution for

$$
x < \ell_i
$$

---

We can start with

$$
x_i = \frac{\ell_{i-1} + \ell_i}{2},
$$

where we use $\ell_0=0$. We then repeat

$$
x_i \mapsto x_i - \frac{f(x_i)}{f'(x_i)}
$$

to optimize the solutions.

Comment: Actually, that's the first thing I tried, but it fails.
Indeed, descent methods are ok for a mono-modal function but this function is far from monomodal. Your algorithm in not constrained to remain in the interval it starts in, and the fact is that it basically jumps erraticaly from its initial interval to an other. In the end, we can not know how many starting points to use to obtain the m solutions for sure. Dichotomy does the job reliably: you consider each interval in turn, and that's it, you have the solution in the interval you start from.

Comment: There is another algorithm to ensure that you remain in the interval. Start with the interval $$[\ell_{i-1},\ell_i].$$ Then continue with the intevral $$\Big[\ell_{i-1},\frac{\ell_{i-1}+\ell_i}{2}\Big],\textrm{ if } f\Big(\frac{\ell_{i-1}+\ell_i}{2}\Big) > 0$$ or $$\Big[\frac{\ell_{i-1}+\ell_i}{2},\ell_i\Big],\textrm{ for } f\Big(\frac{\ell_{i-1}+\ell_i}{2}\Big)< 0.$$And you repeat this.

Comment: Great! On a few experiments, this method requires a bit less (say 10-15 %) iterations that dichotomy to reach the same precision.

Answer (score 0):

$\Sigma \frac{l_i}{l_i-x} = n$

$\Sigma (1 + \frac{x}{l_i-x}) = n$

$m + x\Sigma\frac{1}{l_i-x} = n$

$x \Sigma\frac{1}{l_i-x} = n - m $

I don't think, you may get further with optimalization of this equation.

Regardless on what you do, you'll have to apply Newton or other iterative algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I was drawn to and found to work very well is simply to work by dichotomy. Indeed, there are m solutions to this equation and each solution lies in ]l_i, l_{i+1}[.
It is very straitforward to implement and very efficient.

Comment: Only $m-1$ solutions lie in $[\ell_i,\ell_{i+1}]$, the other lie in $[\infty,\ell_1]$, IF we assume that $\ell_k$ is ordered...